# IP Address Regex allowing for port

Tags: java, regex, ip, port

I have the following regex to match an IP address:

```
(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Could someone please update it to allow for a port number on the end (port number would be optional)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Man, that's a mess. It's better to simplify the search pattern, and then validate values, rather than try to do everything in the regex. e.g.,

```
private String findIP(String in) {
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((\\d+\\.){3}\\d+):(\\d+)").matcher(in);
  if (m.find()) {
    String[] p = m.group(1).split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      if (Integer.parseInt(p[i]) > 255) return null;
    if (Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)) > 65535) return null;
    return m.group(0);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I'm probably not taking everything into account (addresses starting with 0., parseInt returning negatives, etc.), but having a simpler regex pays off for readability, as well as having the numbers 4, 255, and 65535 be cues to the future reader that we're talking about a dotted quad and a port.

Comment: +1, but a better regex is: "([012]?\\d{1,2})(\\.[012]?\\d{1,2}){3}(:(\\d{1,5}))?"

Comment: Thanks Blake, I decided to use yours, I had to make a slight change to make the port optional

(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(:[\d]{1,5})?$

Answer (score 0):

```
(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]):[\d]{1,5}$
```

Comment: The regex *requires* the port.